# Paypal fees to transfer money from business account to personal account in adaptive API

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using Paypal adaptive API to transfer money from a business account to a personal account, but I cant figure out Paypal transaction fees for that

Answer (score 0):

The fee structure for Adaptive Payments would be the same as any PayPal payment. If you are a personal account you do not qualify for any fee reductions. You can see the fee structure at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/

If you choose to pay the fees by setting feesPayer=SENDER you will still pay the standard rate based on the receivers account.